# How do I the extract the first digit from a number (variable in a bash script)?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Let's say the variable `numbers=$@` where `$@`is from user input. The user typed in `./script.sh 901.32.02` and I want to get the first digit `9` and store in another variable. How can I do this? I was told to do

```
  for n in `seq 1 $count`
    do var=${numbers[0]}
  done
```

but that prints out the whole input if I `echo $var` instead of just `9`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488270/how-to-check-the-first-character-in-a-string-in-unix/18488371

Answer (score 13):

In Bash, you can extract the first character using [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
${parameter:offset:length}
```

Example:

```
$ var=901.32.02
$ first_char="${var:0:1}"
$ echo "${first_char}"
9
```

Comment: @Kusalananda Oh, sorry, when I saw your answer it had a different expansion (`"${numbers%%.*}"`) which gives a different output (`901`).

Comment: Ah, yes, because I interpreted "number" as "number" rather than "digit" before I saw my error. Ah well, I'll remove that comment anyway as you added the generic form of the expansion too.

Answer (score 5):

```
numbers='901.32.02'
firstdigit="${numbers:0:1}"

printf 'The first digit is "%s"\n' "$firstdigit"
```

The result of the above is

```
The first digit is "9"
```

The `${numbers:0:1}` parameter expansion in `bash` give you the substring of length 1 from the start of the string (offset zero).  This is a `bash`-specific parameter substitution (also in some other shells, but not in the POSIX standard).

In a POSIX shell, you may also do

```
firstdigit=$( printf "%s\n" "$numbers" | cut -c 1 )
```

This will use `cut` to only return the first character.

Or, using standard parameter expansions,

```
firstdigit="${numbers%${numbers#?}}"
```

This first uses `${numbers#?}` to create a string with the first digit *removed*, then it removes that string from the end of `$numbers` using `${numbers%suffix}` (where `suffix` is the result of the first expansion).

---

The above assumes that the first character of `$numbers` is actually a digit. If it is not, then you would have to first remove non-digits from the start of the value:

```
numbers=$( printf '%s\n' "$numbers" | sed 's/^[^0-9]*//' )
```

or,

```
numbers="${numbers#${numbers%%[0-9]*}}"
```

---

`${numbers[0]}` would have worked if each character was a separate element in the *array* `numbers` (and if the first character was a digit). Since `numbers` is not an array, it's equivalent to just `$numbers`.

Comment: `printf "%.1s" 1234` should do, without needing the `cut`

Answer (score 3):

You can use below method too

```
cat script.sh

   #!/bin/bash
echo $1 | awk '{print substr($1,1,1)}'



 sh script.sh 90

Where 90 is the user input
```

output is 9

Comment: so the above code is correct? it's not working for me though, im using a bash script

Comment: @Rashad Yes, you can easily call the external program `awk` from your bash script and store the results in a bash script variable!

Comment: Note also that the `#!`-line must not be preceded by blank lines or spaces. You are also specifying `bash` as the script language in the script itself, while running it with `sh`.

Answer (score 2):

With colrm

```
echo '901.32.02' | colrm 2
```

Comment: Using this simple method, is there a way to get the 2 last characters?  Thanks

Comment: @KevinLemaire with a know formatted string colrm 0 7. colrm don't handle negative number, perhaps in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect only digits (not other character types) you should use a simple regular expression.

```
[[ ${numbers} =~ ^([[:digit:]]) ]] && var=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

In $var is a digit or it is empty (even not declared).